# VBA Excel - Need a function that finds data in a pattern within a string

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there's a function that will pull out a string that matches a certain pattern. I'm currently trying to pull out this:  "C3-4" Which is located in a string, and is found in multiple different sections. The String also changes, for example it could be L2-3, so I need this function, if it exists, to be able to recognize a pattern, like AX-X (A being a letter, X being a number, and the - being a -) Any help would be much appreciated. Sorry if the question is vague, I don't have any program written yet to help give an example because I need this to give me a baseline to begin programming.

===EDIT===

I Have been able to come up with this, however I think my pattern is incorrect, it evaluates to "no" when it should evaluate to "yes":

```
Sub RegEx_Tester()
Set objRegExp_1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegExp_1.Global = True
objRegExp_1.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp_1.Pattern = "[TSCL][1-13]*-[1-13]"
strToSearch = "L5-1"
Set regExp_Matches = objRegExp_1.Execute(strToSearch)
If regExp_Matches.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Yes")
Else
    MsgBox ("No")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What you need to look up is called a Regular Expression.  Google will give you many examples of this, as will [so] now you know what it's called. Once you've had a look, if you're still having problems, post back with what you have tried and we'll get you sorted out. :)

Comment: @Dave, I have edited the original post to have my new code, I believe the pattern is a little messed up, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

I've modified the pattern a little.  The first grouping requires a single alpha character, followed by numerics that may be one or two digits, followed by a dash (escaped with a \ since otherwise it has a special meaning in a regexp), followed by a single character numeric.  Let me know if you don't see what I've done here and I'll try to explain it a little better...

```
Sub RegEx_Tester()
Set objRegExp_1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegExp_1.Global = True
objRegExp_1.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp_1.Pattern = "[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1}"
strToSearch = "L5-1"

Set regExp_Matches = objRegExp_1.Execute(strToSearch)
WScript.Echo regExp_Matches.Count
If regExp_Matches.Count = 1 Then
    MsgBox ("Yes")
Else
    MsgBox ("No")
End If
End Sub
```